HTML img.src and img.style.display not updating when a player clicks in a Tic Tac Toe game
I was making my first HTML/CSS/JS project when i encountered a bug in my code involving re-using functions of player inputs after reseting the game.


const greenO = "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-png-10.png"
const redX = "https://pnghq.com/wp-content/uploads/pnghq.com-download-red-cross-mark-download-png-hq-png-image.png"

const slots = document.getElementsByClassName("slots")
const slotImages = document.getElementsByClassName("slot-images")

let playerClickAvailable = true
let computerMoveAvailable = false

for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
  slots[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    playerClick(i)
  })
}

function playerClick(i) {
  console.log("playerClick fired with (" + i + ")")
  console.log("player move available: " + playerClickAvailable)
  console.log("computer move available: " + computerMoveAvailable)
  console.log("playerClick fired in slot with img.src " + slotImages[i].src)
  console.log("playerClick fired in slot with img.style.display " + slotImages[i].style.display)

  if (playerClickAvailable) {
    const img = slotImages[i]
    if (img.src === "") {
      img.src = greenO
      img.style.display = "block"

      playerClickAvailable = false
      computerMoveAvailable = true

      if (checkWin() === undefined) {
        setTimeout(computerMove, 750);
      }
    }
  }
}

function computerMove() {
  console.log("player move available: " + playerClickAvailable)
  console.log("computer move available: " + computerMoveAvailable)

  if (computerMoveAvailable) {
    let img = undefined

    let occupiedCount = 0
    for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
      if (slotImages[i].src === "") {
        console.log("breaked after " + (i + 1) + " iteration(s)")
        break
      } else {
        occupiedCount += 1
      }
    }

    if (occupiedCount === 9) {
      console.log("tie")
      document.getElementById("reset").style.display = "block"
      return
    }

    while (true) {
      const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
      img = slotImages[i]
      if (img.src == "") {
        break
      }
    }

    img.src = redX
    img.style.display = "block"

    playerClickAvailable = true
    computerMoveAvailable = false

    checkWin()
  }
}

function giveWin(slot) {
  function blockMoves() {
    playerClickAvailable = false
    computerMoveAvailable = false
  }

  const reset = document.getElementById("reset")
  if (slot === greenO) {
    console.log("player won")
    reset.style.display = "block"
    blockMoves()
    return "player"
  } else if (slot === redX) {
    console.log("computer won")
    reset.style.display = "block"
    blockMoves()
    return "computer"
  }
}

function checkWin() {
  const first = slotImages[0].src
  const second = slotImages[1].src
  const third = slotImages[2].src
  const fourth = slotImages[3].src
  const fifth = slotImages[4].src
  const sixth = slotImages[5].src
  const seventh = slotImages[6].src
  const eighth = slotImages[7].src
  const ninth = slotImages[8].src

  if (
    (first === second && first === third) ||
    (first === fourth && first === seventh) ||
    (first === fifth && first === ninth)
  ) {
    giveWin(first)
  } else if (
    second === fifth && second === eighth
  ) {
    giveWin(second)
  } else if (
    (third === sixth && third === ninth) ||
    (third === fifth && third === seventh)
  ) {
    giveWin(third)
  } else if (
    fourth === fifth && fourth === sixth
  ) {
    giveWin(fourth)
  } else if (
    seventh === eighth && seventh === ninth
  ) {
    giveWin(seventh)
  }
}

function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    const img = slotImages[i]
    img.src = ""
    img.style.display = "none"
  }

  document.getElementById("reset").style.display = "none"

  playerClickAvailable = true
  computerMoveAvailable = false

  console.log("reseted")
}
body {
  min-height: 800;
  min-width: 800;
}

.center-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#main-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.slots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 10px solid rgb(71, 71, 71);
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.slot-images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#reset {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  display: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#reset-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#game-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<div id="game-container">
  <div id="main-container">
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
    <button class="slots"><img class="slot-images"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="reset-container">
  <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset!</button>
</div>



I have put many console.log() statements to debug and everything seemed correct but after the reset() function runs, when the player clicks, the img.src and img.style.display dont update, and everything past that breaks.
I tried updating and presetting the values to see if anything changed, but it didn't work, the only way I could fix it was by doing:
location.reload()
in the end of the reset() function.
But I know thats's a bad way to do it and in the future i want to make a scoreboard, etc...

This is failing after a game has been reset:
if (img.src === "")

Because this has a side-effect you didn't expect:
img.src = ""

When setting to an empty string like that, the resulting DOM element is:
<img src class="slot-images">

or perhaps:
<img src="" class="slot-images">

Browsers do what they can to quietly "correct" HTML, and in the event of an attribute which expects a URL that "correction" is to try to infer what it can about the URL.  This allows for relative paths to exist, for example.  And what it infers about a blank URL is to use the URL for the current page.
So after a reset, any time you compare the empty src with "" it will fail because the "empty src" is actually the current page's URL, not an empty string.

Following the same pattern you have for image files, add another one to some default image.  For example:
const empty = "https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png";

Initialize all of your images to that:
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">

And use that value throughout the logic.  Such as when resetting the game:
img.src = empty

And when comparing the value in determining a move:
if (img.src === empty)


For example:


const empty = "https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png";
const greenO = "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-circle-png-10.png"
const redX = "https://pnghq.com/wp-content/uploads/pnghq.com-download-red-cross-mark-download-png-hq-png-image.png"

const slots = document.getElementsByClassName("slots")
const slotImages = document.getElementsByClassName("slot-images")

let playerClickAvailable = true
let computerMoveAvailable = false

for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
  slots[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    playerClick(i)
  })
}

function playerClick(i) {
  console.log("playerClick fired with (" + i + ")")
  console.log("player move available: " + playerClickAvailable)
  console.log("computer move available: " + computerMoveAvailable)
  console.log("playerClick fired in slot with img.src " + slotImages[i].src)
  console.log("playerClick fired in slot with img.style.display " + slotImages[i].style.display)

  if (playerClickAvailable) {
    const img = slotImages[i]
    if (img.src === empty) {
      img.src = greenO
      img.style.display = "block"

      playerClickAvailable = false
      computerMoveAvailable = true

      if (checkWin() === undefined) {
        setTimeout(computerMove, 750);
      }
    }
  }
}

function computerMove() {
  console.log("player move available: " + playerClickAvailable)
  console.log("computer move available: " + computerMoveAvailable)

  if (computerMoveAvailable) {
    let img = undefined

    let occupiedCount = 0
    for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
      if (slotImages[i].src === empty) {
        console.log("breaked after " + (i + 1) + " iteration(s)")
        break
      } else {
        occupiedCount += 1
      }
    }

    if (occupiedCount === 9) {
      console.log("tie")
      document.getElementById("reset").style.display = "block"
      return
    }

    while (true) {
      const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
      img = slotImages[i]
      if (img.src == empty) {
        break
      }
    }

    img.src = redX
    img.style.display = "block"

    playerClickAvailable = true
    computerMoveAvailable = false

    checkWin()
  }
}

function giveWin(slot) {
  function blockMoves() {
    playerClickAvailable = false
    computerMoveAvailable = false
  }

  const reset = document.getElementById("reset")
  if (slot === greenO) {
    console.log("player won")
    reset.style.display = "block"
    blockMoves()
    return "player"
  } else if (slot === redX) {
    console.log("computer won")
    reset.style.display = "block"
    blockMoves()
    return "computer"
  }
}

function checkWin() {
  const first = slotImages[0].src
  const second = slotImages[1].src
  const third = slotImages[2].src
  const fourth = slotImages[3].src
  const fifth = slotImages[4].src
  const sixth = slotImages[5].src
  const seventh = slotImages[6].src
  const eighth = slotImages[7].src
  const ninth = slotImages[8].src

  if (
    (first === second && first === third) ||
    (first === fourth && first === seventh) ||
    (first === fifth && first === ninth)
  ) {
    giveWin(first)
  } else if (
    second === fifth && second === eighth
  ) {
    giveWin(second)
  } else if (
    (third === sixth && third === ninth) ||
    (third === fifth && third === seventh)
  ) {
    giveWin(third)
  } else if (
    fourth === fifth && fourth === sixth
  ) {
    giveWin(fourth)
  } else if (
    seventh === eighth && seventh === ninth
  ) {
    giveWin(seventh)
  }
}

function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    const img = slotImages[i]
    img.src = empty
    img.style.display = "none"
  }

  document.getElementById("reset").style.display = "none"

  playerClickAvailable = true
  computerMoveAvailable = false

  console.log("reseted")
}
body {
  min-height: 800;
  min-width: 800;
}

.center-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#main-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.slots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 10px solid rgb(71, 71, 71);
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.slot-images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#reset {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  display: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#reset-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#game-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<div id="game-container">
  <div id="main-container">
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
    <button class="slots">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/mwFzF.png" class="slot-images">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="reset-container">
  <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset!</button>
</div>



